# Is "VPATH" applied recursively, to further relocate an already-relocated-target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

`GPATH` has a special feature.

It allows Make to recursively search for a missing target, by ***repeatedly*** applying the same `VPATH` on a given target.

Thus: `all` can turn to `D/D/D/D/D/all` (`VPATH` applied 5 times!), and so on.

This rather bizarre - and frankly buggy - relocation, that Make performs on its targets, ***doesn't*** occur for a "normal" `VPATH`. Thus, for a "regular" `VPATH`, Make will still apply the VAPTH ***once***, and ***only once***.

But, as soon as you add `GPATH` into the mix, Make goes out of its way, by doing a fully-exhaustive recursive-vpath-search, relocating the missing target to a directory - as deep as make could possible match - by repeatedly and recursively applying again and again the same `VPATH`.

***For example, given a makefile, like:***

```make
# Force Make, to do a "directory-search" (via VPATH), for the non-existent file 'all'
$(shell rm -rf 'all')
# Make sure, that all of the (vpath) files - 'D/all', 'D/D/all' and so on - DO NOT exist!
$(shell rm -rf 'D')


VPATH = D

all :
    @echo '$@'



D/all :
D/D/all :
D/D/D/all :
D/D/D/D/all :
D/D/D/D/D/all :
```

***Executing, I get:***

```console
# 'VAPTH' alone. (i.e. no 'GPATH').
$ make 
D/all

# Adding 'GPATH = D', causes Make to do an "exhaustive" recursive-directory-search.
# This recursive serach, has no limits, regarding the number of times, Make will apply the same VPATH on a given target.
$ make -f makefile -f <(echo 'GPATH = D')
D/D/D/D/D/all
```

Bug or feature? What do you think?


***(Versions note: 3.82 and up).***